# Download files and folders from FTP

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, windows

I needed to download files from FTP using vb.NET. I found the solution to my problem over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732999/download-file-from-ftp-if-it-does-not-exist-in-a-given-list-of-local-files).

The problem now is that the code helps me to download the files from the parent folder but if there are any sub-folders, they remain untouched. Is there a work-around for it?
Regards

Comment: You'll have to call the function recursively. Have a look at what you get if you run GetDirectories.

Comment: It gets the path of the current directory.

Comment: No not GetDirectory, GetDirectories. Something like this: "For Each dir As FTPfileInfo In ftp.ListDirectoryDetail("/").GetDirectories"

Answer (score 0):

The CodeProject FTP library you are using isnt exactly great for recursive access.

Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913312/downloading-all-files-using-ftp-and-c-sharp).  Its c# but answers your question.  You can (almost) always convert c# to vb.net!

Comment: I think you should be a bit more specific about which post you mean, since none of the answers are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with lftp in a one liner.

```
lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow off;  mirror  htdocs/assets/" -d -u 
username,password  ftp://ftpwhatever.net/htdocs/
```

This will copy the whole directory
`/assets/` to your local working directory